# Uninstall Office 2013 Sp1 silently without removing Office

Tags: uninstall, microsoft-office-2013, service-pack

For uninstalling Office 2007/2010 Service Packs, Microsoft provided a separate tool(OARPMAN.exe) that could be downloaded and used for silent uninstallation of Service Packs.

I was unable to find such a tool for Office 2013 Service Pack. Can anybody provide a link to the tool if available.

If not, any suggestions on silent uninstall of SP1 2013 would be very helpful.